# C++ Winsock Server with Multiple Clients?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock, bittorrent

I have written a program that talks to a Bittorrent tracker via a TCP connection. I want to expand it's functionality to talk to multiple trackers at the same time via winsock in C++.

Do I need to have multiple sockets?
If so, do I need to initialize a WSADATA structure for each socket?

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/examples/basics/select-server.html). Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one socket per TCP connection, i.e. one per remote IP/port pair. You only need to call [`WSAStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) once to initialize [winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) library.